# How to resize react ace editor in react app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ace-editor

I am using React Ace {https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ace} in my React app and I am showing the previews of user entered HTML, CSS and JavaScript below input like this:
[Code Editor Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyOob.png)

I want to make user able to adjust the height of editor and preview by dragging by at bottom of editor like CodePen.

I tried to resize with all of available questions in Stack Overflow but the main problem occurs that only the height of editor container increases but the lines of Ace editor remain same as before.
Moreover all of available answers of Stack Overflow are in static HTML page where they are using it like a variable

```
var editor = ace.edit( "smyles_editor" );
```

(like this):
[Stack Overflow Question Crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf8iH.png)
which I used in my React app like this:
[My Code Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDt8S.png)
I rename the "ace" variable with "AceEditor" which I import in react from npm module, but it is giving me error like this:
[Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I7fl.png)

I want to make it resizable in a React app

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok brother I will take of this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact method of resizing, Ace container may not get a `resize` event to cause it to re-adjust, but you can throw it yourself, like so:

```js
var e = new CustomEvent("resize");
e.initEvent("resize");
window.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: I am not that expert in react, but can you please explain how I can then use that resize event and how react ace will behave to that event?

Comment: Great news, I am not an expert in React either - illustrated solution is how I solved the "editor gets taller but displayed lines remain the same" problem when using Ace in plain JS, with this code going into the same place where you change Ace editor's height. None of the screenshots of code feature anything related to resizing, so there's not much to add.